# How can I avoid inserting DATE if the DATE is already exists in database to avoid duplicates?

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I'm making reservation for our school project. I want to make sure `mysqli` rejects the insertion of the `reservationDate` inside the database table `"tbl_funeral"` if the values already exist inside the database. The problem is data is inserted even if the data is already exist in database. This code doesn't seem to work, so I was wondering if you guys could check my code to see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php 
     $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "parishdb");

    if(isset($_POST["btnSavess"])){
        $conn->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_funeral(FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, DateOfDeath, Address, ReservationDate, SelectTime) VALUES('$_POST[firstName]', '$_POST[lastName]', '$_POST[dob]', '$_POST[dod]', '$_POST[address]', '$_POST[reservationDate]','$_POST[selectTime]')");

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

         if ( mysqli_num_rows ($result) >= 1 ){
               echo "New record created successfully";
             } else {
               echo "data already exists";
            }
             mysqli_close($conn);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One sensible way to approach this is to handle it at the database level, and add a unique constraint on the `ReservationDate` column:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_funeral ADD CONSTRAINT date_cnstr UNIQUE (ReservationDate);
```

With this constraint in place, any insert which attempted to use a reservation date which already appears in the table would on the database itself.

You may use a pattern similar to the following in your PHP code:

```
try {
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "parishdb");

    if(isset($_POST["btnSavess"])) {
        $conn->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_funeral(FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, DateOfDeath, Address, ReservationDate, SelectTime) VALUES('$_POST[firstName]', '$_POST[lastName]', '$_POST[dob]', '$_POST[dod]', '$_POST[address]', '$_POST[reservationDate]','$_POST[selectTime]')");

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if ($query === FALSE) {
            throw new Exception($this->mysqli->error);
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
    }

} catch(Exception $e) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that I see you are not using prepared statements yet.  You should consider using them to avoid SQL injection and make your code more readable.

Comment: I don't need to add if statement?

Comment: @MomoyPH My suggestion is to handle this within MySQL itself.  I'm not a PHP guru, but I tried to modify your code to handle a unique constraint violation.

Comment: where do I put this query `ALTER TABLE tbl_funeral ADD CONSTRAINT date_cnstr UNIQUE (ReservationDate);` ?

Comment: @MomoyPH You run this directly from MySQL, if you can.  This is a permanent change I am suggesting that you make.

Comment: sorry but I don't know how do I do it. I'm just a beginner on PHP. I try the try catch but seem not working at all keep inserting same data

Comment: Try doing an insert directly on MySQL with a duplicate reservation date.  Does that query fail?

Comment: I have a question how can I run the query directly to my MySQL to make it permanent?

Comment: Just run the `ALTER TABLE` statement from MySQL and it should work.  Now I'm wondering _where_ you have been running it...

Comment: How can I throw an error if user enter a same date?

Comment: @MomoyPH You may check your PHP code to see what happens.  I would expect that either PHP would throw an exception, _or_ the query would return `FALSE`.  In either case, you should be able to handle it.